# Bigquery : destination table is empty after creating a temporary table through query rest api

Tags: google-bigquery

how can I check the destination table with the dataset?

*query executed successfully.*

**Method**: [jobs.query](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query?authuser=1)

**inputbody**:

```
{
  "query": "BEGIN CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP TABLE test(name STRING); END;",
  "useLegacySql": false
}
```

**response**:

```
 {
  "kind": "bigquery#queryResponse",
  "jobReference": {
    "projectId": "proj",
    "jobId": "job_Rl_W",
    "location": "US"
  },
  "totalBytesProcessed": "0",
  "jobComplete": true
}
```

*but when I get job response using job API*

**job response**:

```
{
  "kind": "bigquery#job",
  "etag": "##########",
  "id": "proj:US.job_Rl_W",
  "selfLink": "it exists don't worry about it",
  "user_email": "myemail@email.com",
  "configuration": {
    "query": {
      "query": "BEGIN CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP TABLE test(name STRING); END;",
      "priority": "INTERACTIVE",
      "useLegacySql": false
    },
    "jobType": "QUERY"
  },
  "jobReference": {
    "projectId": "proj",
    "jobId": "job_Rl_W",
    "location": "US"
  },
  "statistics": {
    "creationTime": "1614085055222",
    "startTime": "1614085055304",
    "endTime": "1614085056395",
    "totalBytesProcessed": "0",
    "query": {
      "totalBytesProcessed": "0",
      "totalBytesBilled": "0",
      "totalSlotMs": "0",
      "statementType": "SCRIPT"
    },
    "totalSlotMs": "0",
    "numChildJobs": "1"
  },
  "status": {
    "state": "DONE"
  }
}
```

**as u can see there is no destination table in the job response under configuration**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I try **[Method: jobs.list](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/list)** API

and my jobId to ***parentJobId param***.
I'm able to get destination table for temp table.